PDF: Opciones comboBox dinámicas
En un formulario pdf, tengo un "Menú desplegable", en el que hay distintas opciones. Por ejemplo "Colores" de un producto.
Hoy solo hay opción de "Blanco" y "Negro", pero mañana puede ser "Blanco", "Negro" y "Gris".
El contenido de las opciones del "Menú desplegable", se puede hacer que esten en un archivo a parte y cuando seleccionemos el "Menú desplegable", una de las acciones que realice al estar el "campo activo" sea llenar las opciones del desplegable con el contenido del archivo?
Esto tiene sentido si las opciones del menú cambian constantemente. De esta manera solo modificando el archivo que importará, no hay que ir modificando el formulario pdf.
También es útil si las opciones del desplegable se encuentran en otros formularios y por tanto haya un archivo común que sirva para llenar las opciones del desplegable en varios formularios.
He hecho la prueba con la lectura de un archivo fdf. El problema es que solo lo incorpora como resultado, no como opción del desplegable
Contenido archivo *.fdf
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</FDF<</F(NombreArchivo.pdf)/Fields[<</T(Desplegable1)/V(Blanco)>>]/ID[<4AC965A1D4B129449B7DE4892AC8B8A4>]/UF(NombreArchivo.pdf)>>/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
En esta parte, como habría que poner varias opciones.
Ejemplo:
[<</T(Desplegable1)/V(Blanco)/V(Negro)...>>]
He de decir que no sé si la solución es a través de un archivo fdf.
Muchas gracias
